# Capture verbose stream without enabling -Verbose

Tags: powershell, verbose

Maybe there's no way to do this in PowerShell.

If I have the file `verboseTest.ps1`

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]    # CmdletBinding attribute enables -verbose flag
Param()
Write-Verbose 'verbose test'
```

If I call `.\verboseTest.ps1`, I see nothing as expected.

If I call `.\verboseTest.ps1 -Verbose` I see the output.

> VERBOSE: verbose test outer

as expected.

But if I call `.\verboseTest.ps1 4>&1` I don't.  The verbose stream is lost.

Now, Info behaves completely differently.

I have the file `infoTest.ps1` and it behaves sanely.

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]    # Add CmdletBinding attribute
Param()
Write-Information 'info test outer'
```

If I call `.\infoTest.ps1`, I see nothing as expected.

If I call `.\infoTest.ps1 -InformationAction 'Continue'`, which is analogous to the `-Verbose` flag, it succeeds and outputs `info test outer` to the console.

And if I call `.\infoTest.ps1 6>&1` it *also* outputs `info test outer` to the console!  So somehow the "information" stream behaves completely differently from the "verbose" stream.

The behavior of the info stream makes sense.  The write-information commands write to the stream, and I can redirect it or view it or not as I see fit.  The "verbose" does not!  I have to enable showing it in the output in order to redirect it?  Am I doing something wrong?  How does this make sense?

Do I *have* to enable verbose preference in order to redirect the output?  And if so, can I do that inside the method or does it change it globally session-wide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, **the verbose stream (stream number `4`) isn't just *silent* when not explicitly turned on, but *no data is written to it*.**

That is, `Write-Verbose` statements are effective *no-ops*<sup>[1]</sup>, unless `-Verbose` is passed or preference variable `$VerbosePreference` is set to `Continue`.

---

Among PowerShell's silent-by-default output streams - verbose (`4`), debug (`5`) and information (`6`) - **the information stream is the lone exception: `Write-Information` statements *always* write to it, whether it happens to be silenced or not.**

---

**Setting preference variable `$VerbosePreference` to `Continue` turns on verbose output for all commands in the current scope and any child scopes** - but there's an **important exception**:

***Advanced functions* implemented in *modules* see only a *global* instance of `$VerbosePreference`** when called from a script; by contrast, binary *cmdlets* are *not* affected.
This highly problematic behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).

You can **work around** that problem as follows:

```
# Create a script-local copy of the global parameter-defaults
# hashtable.
# Note: If you want to clear the global presets, call .Clear()
#       after cloning.
$PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()

# Preset the -Verbose switch for all commands that support it.
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Verbose'] = $true

# ... call commands, which will behave as if -Verbose had been passed.
```

---

<sup>[1] However, the cmdlet is still *called*, which means that arguments you pass to it are evaluated, so it is hypothetically still possible for a silent `Write-Verbose` call to have side effects, such as when passing an expandable string as the message that contains a subexpression (`$(...)`) with side effects.</sup>